# Issue with google-maps-api, polygons wont appear on map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load N number of polygons onto a google map in react using @react-google-maps/api, however the map loads, the website indicates no errors, but the polygons are not present on the map. I have a MapComponent.js block to handle the map that I think is the issue, but I can't figure out why.
I have seen a previous question where the solution was to disable StrictMode in index.js, and this works, but some mentioned that this is discouraged. Is there a better solution?

Below are the necessary components for the map:

```
const MapComponent = ({ center, polygons }) => {
  const mapStyles = {
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100%"
  };

  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
        zoom={14}
        center={center}
      >
        {polygons.map((polygon, index) => (
          <Polygon
            key={index}
            path={polygon}
            options={{ fillColor: "#93c47d", fillOpacity: 0.1 }}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
}

export default MapComponent;
```

In App.js, Im loading in this component like so: `{center && <MapComponent center={center} polygons={polygons} />}`

The polygons object is a list with objects like this:

```
const examplePolygon = [
  {
    lat: 37.770, 
    lng: -122.510
  },
  {
    lat: 37.775,
    lng: -122.512
  },
  {
    lat: 37.775, 
    lng: -122.505
  },
  {
    lat: 37.770,
    lng: -122.505
  },
  {
    lat: 37.770, 
    lng: -122.510
  }
];
```

That I make with this line in App.js: `const [Polygons, setPolygons] = useState([examplePolygon]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things

1. In your `GoogleMap` compoent, a `defaultCenter` is needed but is missing based on the code you provided
2. (might not matter but a great improvement) The `Polygon` component supposed to accept an array for the `path` properties. In other words, you need to completely skip the `polygons.map` part, and just pass `polygons` array to the `path` prop of the `Polygon`

With above in mind, your code should look like this

```
<LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={15}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 37.77, lng: -122.51 }}
    options={{ styles: mapStyles }}
  >
   {polygons.map((p, i) => {
      return (
        <Polygon
          key={i}
          path={p}
          options={{ fillColor: '#93c47d', fillOpacity: 0.1 }}
        />
      )
    })}
  </GoogleMap>
</LoadScript>
```

See more about `GoogleMap` component https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap

Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-wildflower-378pwj?file=/src/Main.js:936-1190

Comment: I see in the code sandbox example that `polygons` is an array of just one polygon. Im trying to pass N number of polygons into the map, hence the map of `polygons` to various polygon objects. I realize that my original question did not make this clear, so my mistake

Comment: @Soup Hey i updated the codesandbox app. I am not sure what's your `ploygons` payload looks like, but I was able to get multiple polygons show up. So its prob best to either have you take a look at the example app, or post what payload are you passing into the component so we can provide further help. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! you were right about the payload (flipped lat and long), there was an issue with it and once I caught it, it worked!